# storing data from remote server to local server using sqlite.net (sqlite + mysql + json.net xamarin.android)

Tags: c#, php, mysql, sqlite, xamarin.android

I am using xamarin.android visual studio 2015 and also Mysql as remote server and sqlite as a local server and i am using webclient to connect C# to mysql using php and retrieving data from remote server using json formate.

sir i am dealing with an issue of when userlogin once den he should not login again and again but for this i need your userid which is on remote server (MySql) to store it in locally(Sqlite) and i am able to download all the user details in a form of json array string but now i don't have any idea about how to store it in sqlite table den use this sqlite table to not do login again and again for one user . can u please help me out as i stuck here very badly

i put all my code here
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/76603/storing-data-from-remote-server-to-local-server-using-sqlite-net/p1?new=1

and if my coding is wrong den please give me other coding as its really very important.

tell me about this  part:

```
  string json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Result);
            var Login_json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
            //mAdapter = new jsonAdapter(this, login);
            Toast.MakeText(this, Login_json.ToString(), ToastLength.Short).Show();
            // mlogin = JsonConvert.deserializeObject<List<Login1>>(json);
            try
            {
                string dpPath =
                    Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal),
                        "Masteruser.db3"); //Create New Database  
                var db = new SQLiteConnection(dpPath);
                db.CreateTable<Login_Sqlite>();
                Login_Sqlite tbl = new Login_Sqlite();

                Toast.MakeText(this, "table created,", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                tbl.userid = Login_json.ToString();
                tbl.username = Login_json.ToString();
                tbl.mobile_no = Login_json.ToString();
                tbl.password = Login_json.ToString();
                tbl.email = Login_json.ToString();
                tbl.role = Login_json.ToString();
                tbl.datetime = Login_json.ToString();
                db.Insert(tbl);

                //Toast.MakeText(this, "Record Added Successfully...,", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                var activity2 = new Intent(this, typeof(HomeActivity));
                activity2.PutExtra("userid", tbl.userid.ToString());
                activity2.PutExtra("mobile_no", tbl.mobile_no.ToString());
                StartActivity(activity2);

                Toast.MakeText(this, tbl.userid, ToastLength.Short).Show();
                Toast.MakeText(this, tbl.mobile_no, ToastLength.Short).Show();
```

I am inserting "`Login_json.ToString();`" to each row of sqlite table but it give me output as a full array but i want only data of specific data eg "userid" keyword in tbl.userid but its not happening.

please guys help in changing code of this line so that i can able to store data to specific keyword in a table.
hope u all understanding what i am trying to tell u . 
Thank you.